# Reusing adapter for realm objects

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, realm

I was wondering which ways is best to pass an adapter from one activity to another.
Here is my point; I'm using realm as ContentProvider and the a recyclerview to display some data. My realResults variable has a changelistener with the following onChange():

```
    public void onChange() {
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          ...
```

So anytimes my data changes onChange() is called and my recyclerview gets updated which is pretty cool.
In another activity I call

```
 adater.notifyItemRemoved();
```

This call is immediately unfortunately followed by

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

so that the animation for the removed item is not visible.
To make the animation be visible to the user, I would like to avoid callingnotifyDataSetChanged within onChange() as above.
To do that I think of having some kind of helper class with a method such as

```
public static Adapter getAdapter();
```

With the returned Adapter I would call either notifyDataSetChanged() or  notifyItemRemoved() depending on the situation.

My question is to know whether having such a helper class, as described above, is a good idea or is there a better to pass an adapter from one activity to another?

Thanks

Comment: I think it is not a good idea to pass a adapter or use static getter to access adapter from another activity. You can do it, but it coupled too much things together which is against the design idea of Android. You use case will be supported well after Realm's finegrained notifications https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/989 . For now, one idea is you can maintain your own list of `RealmObject` and checking if the object is removed by `RealmObject.isValid` in the onChange(). Obviously, if you have a long list, this won't be the optimized way since it has to traverse the list.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have come up with a workaround.

In my adapter class I do override the

```
getItemId(int position)
```

method and I also do call

```
adapter.setHasStableIds(true)
```

when setting the recycler view's adapter. The recycler view will then detect any insertion and removal of item and animate itself as appropriate.